# JSTL and JSP problem in a Java web application

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am working on Java web application where I am populating 2 beans by setting up JDBC with my database. I use JSP to view the pages and I am getting proper results in form of tables. One of my table have data about drivers and passengers. The bean is being populated with the entire data. Now I need to utilize JSTL tags to only view the drivers details. So I wrote the following chunk of codes in JSP. I think I am having some problem with the if tag. When I remove it I get the answer but it includes both drivers and passengers. Any suggestions..

```
<table  width="100%" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "0" border= "0">
<c:forEach items='${detailBean.personBean}' var='person' varStatus='status'>
<c:if test='${person.role=='DRIVER' }'>

<tr><td nowrap width = "10%" align="right"><c:out value="VEHNO: " /> </td> <td nowrap  align="left"> <c:out value='${person.vehNo}'/></td></tr>

<tr><td nowrap width = "10%" align="right"><c:out value="ROLE: " /></td> <td nowrap align="left"> <c:out value='${person.role}'/></td></tr>

<tr><td nowrap width = "10%" align="right"><c:out value="DRVRFLAG: " /></td> <td nowrap align="left"> <c:out value='${person.drvrFlag}'/></td></tr>

</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: You wrote "So I wrote the following chunk of codes in JSP"
Where is Code ?

Comment: I am trying to print the codes, but it doesnot get printed here..

Comment: Please read the message formatting rules on the right hand from the message editor (while editing message). Please make use of the preview area below the message editor to verify if anything look right. I'll edit your question for you.

Comment: thanks a lot but I am trying to include the JSP codes, but it doesnot show up in the preview as well as in the edited post.

Comment: I hope you all could see the codes now. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of quotes is invalid. Try to follow the standard convention to always use doublequotes for attribute values and use singlequotes only inside EL expressions. Especially the `c:if` is wrongly quoted. It should look like this:

```
<c:if test="${person.role=='DRIVER'}">
```

However, I wonder that it kind of worked for you because it should have yielded a JSP parser error. That might be server dependent.

Comment: Thanks a lot BaluC, my problem got solved...Your comments have been very useful for me. Could you forward me any JSTL related website where I could learn more?

Comment: You're welcome. I already recommended in one of your previous answers to have a look at the coreservlets.com tutorials: [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) :) The JSTL and EL are covered in the second part: [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html). Here's a [direct link to the PDF](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/ajax/JSTL.pdf). Good luck.